Combinatorial Torsion via $\tau$-chains
I am currently reading "Introduction to Combinatorial Torsions" by Turaev and I am trying to understand a proof. Specifically, in section 2.1, he provides a method for computing torsions of acyclic chain complexes via $\tau$-chains. The theorem is stated as
Theorem 2.2 Any matrix $\tau$-chain $\alpha = (\alpha_0, \alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_m)$ for $C$ with $\det S_i(\alpha)\neq 0$ for all even $i$ is non-degenerate and
$$\tau(C) = \prod_{i=0}^m\det S_i(\alpha)^{(-1)^{i+1}}.$$
The objects in the Theorem above are defined as follows: $C$ is an acyclic chain complex
$$0\to C_m\xrightarrow{\partial{m-1}} C_{m-1}\to\cdots\to C_1\xrightarrow{\partial_0} C_0\to 0$$
Now, let $A_i = (a^i_{jk})$ be the matrix of the linear transformation $\partial_i$, written in terms of the basis $c_i$ of $C_i$, and $c_{i+1}$ of $C_{i+1}$, thus $j\in \{1,\ldots, \dim C_i\}$ and $k\in \{1,\ldots,\dim C_{i+1}\}$. Define a matrix chain $\alpha = (\alpha_0,\ldots, \alpha_m)$ to be a collection of sets $\alpha_i\subset \{1,\ldots, \dim C_i\}$ and $\alpha_0 = \varnothing$. Thus, $S_i(\alpha)$ is defined as the submatrix of $A_i$ formed by the entries $a_{jk}^i$ with $j\in \alpha_{i+1}$ and  $k\not\in \alpha_i$.
The matrix chain $\alpha$ is called a $\tau$-chain if every matrix $S_i(\alpha)$ is a square matrix. Also, if $\det S_i(\alpha)\neq 0$ for all $i$, $\alpha$ is called non-degenerate.
The part with the computation of $\tau(C)$ is no problem for me. The only thing I don't understand is how $\det S_i(\alpha)\neq 0$ for $i$ even imply that $\alpha$ is non-degenerate.
I have tried to view the $j$-rows of $A_i$ with $j\in \alpha_{i+1}$ as basis vectors for the image of $A_i$, but it didn't seem to help me at all. If anyone could help me understand such a proof I would appreciate a lot.

Your post should be sufficiently self-contained that other readers and potential answerers shouldn't have to read through an external article.  To this end, I suggest you define the terms you use more clearly ($\tau$-chain, $C$, $S_i$, $A_i$, etc.).

Thank you for the advice, I've edited the question to contain such definitions.

Turaev gives a more basis-explicit argument in his book, so I'm going to present a more abstract approach to this problem.
For each $i \geq 0$, let $D_i \subseteq C_i$ be the subspace spanned by the basis vectors indexed by $\alpha_i$ and $E_i \subseteq C_i$ the complementary subspace.  Then we have a levelwise decomposition of $C$ (but not a decomposition of chain complexes) given by $$0 \to D_m \oplus E_m \to \cdots \to D_2 \oplus E_2 \xrightarrow{\partial_1} D_1 \oplus E_1 \xrightarrow{\partial_0} D_0 \oplus E_0 \rightarrow 0.$$  Write $S_i = S_i(\alpha)$ for the restriction of $\partial_i$ to $D_{i+1} \to E_i$.  Furthermore, since $\alpha$ is a matrix $\tau$-chain, we have $D_0 = 0$ and $\dim D_{i+1} = \dim E_i$ for all $i \geq 0$.
We want to show the following: if $S_i: D_{i+1} \to E_i$ is an isomorphism for all even $i$, then $S_i$ is an isomorphism for all odd $i$ as well.  We shall argue inductively that $S_i$ is an isomorphism for all $i \geq 0$.
The base case of the induction is given to us: $S_0: D_1 \to E_0$ is an isomorphism.  The crux of the inductive step is "peeling off" previous isomorphisms $S_i: D_{i+1} \to E_i$.  For example, $$0 \rightarrow D_1 \xrightarrow{S_0} E_0 \rightarrow 0$$ is a subcomplex of $C$.  The cokernel, or quotient, of the inclusion of this subcomplex into $C$ is $$0 \to D_m \oplus E_m \to \cdots \to D_2 \oplus E_2 \xrightarrow{\partial_1} E_1 \rightarrow 0 \to 0.$$  Here, we used the fact that $D_0 = 0$; indeed, counterexamples to the proposition can be constructed otherwise.  Furthermore, both the subcomplex $(0 \to D_1 \xrightarrow{S_0} E_0 \to 0)$ and $C$ are acyclic - the former because $S_0$ is an isomorphism - so an argument using the long exact sequence in homology shows that the cokernel complex is acyclic as well.
With this new complex in hand, we want to show that $S_1: D_2 \to E_1$ is an isomorphism.  Since $\dim D_2 = \dim E_1$, it suffices to show that $S_1$ is onto.  We already know that $\partial_1: D_2 \oplus E_2 \to E_1$ is onto by exactness.  Moreover, using the fact that $S_2: D_3 \to E_2$ is an isomorphism we can show that $\partial_1(E_2) \subseteq \partial_1(D_2)$, so $S_1: D_2 \to E_1$ must already be onto.  To see that $\partial_1(E_2) \subseteq \partial_1(D_2)$, write $i_{E_2}$, $p_{E_2}$, etc. for the inclusions and projections for $E_2 \subseteq C_2$, etc..  Then, $$\partial_1 i_{E_2} = \partial_1 i_{E_2} S_2 S_2^{-1} = \partial_1 i_{E_2} p_{E_2} \partial_2 i_{D_3} S_2^{-1} = \partial_1 (1 - i_{D_2} p_{D_2}) \partial_2 i_{D_3} S_2^{-1} = -\partial_1 i_{D_2} p_{D_2} \partial_2 i_{D_3} S_2^{-1}.$$ This completes the proof that $S_1$ is an isomorphism.
Now, continue peeling away the subcomplex $$0 \rightarrow D_2 \xrightarrow{S_1} E_1 \rightarrow 0.$$  We get another complex $$0 \to D_m \oplus E_m \to \cdots \to D_3 \oplus E_3 \xrightarrow{\partial_2} E_2 \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow 0 \to 0,$$ and by hypothesis, $S_2: D_3 \to E_2$ is an isomorphism.  We are in the exact same position from where we started, except we're two indices up.  Hence, by induction all the $S_i: D_{i+1} \to E_i$ are isomorphisms, as desired.

There is also a way to conveniently package this argument into a spectral sequence.  Consider the following ascending filtration on the chain complex $C$: for $p \geq 0$, $$F_p C = (\cdots \to 0 \to D_p \xrightarrow{\partial_{p-1}} C_{p-1} \to \cdots \to C_1 \xrightarrow{\partial_0} C_0 \to 0).$$
The $E^0$ page of the associated spectral sequence is given by $$E^0_{p,q} = \begin{cases} D_{p+1}, & q = 1 \\ E_p, & q = 0 \\ 0, & \text{else}. \end{cases}$$  The zeroth differential $d^0$ is zero except in bidegrees $E^0_{p,1} \to E^0_{p,0}$, where it is precisely the map $S_p: D_{p+1} \to E_p$.  By assumption, $S_p$ is an isomorphism when $p$ is even, so we have $E^1_{p,q} = 0$ unless $p$ is odd and $q \in \{0,1\}$.  Then,  all higher differentials are zero by lacunary reasons and the spectral sequence collapses at the $E^1$ page.
On the other hand, we know that that the spectral sequence abuts to zero since the complex $C$ is acyclic.  Hence, the differentials $d^0: E^0_{p,1} \to E^0_{p,0}$ must be isomorphisms for all $p$, i.e., $S_p$ are isomorphisms for all $p$.

Thank you very much, your answer was super helpful. I fully understood your first approach, although it is still hard for me to understand what is actually happening in terms of matrices, maybe I need more time studying such a solution to visualize it.
Unfortunately I know nothing about spectral sequences, so I didn't quite understand the second approach, but it is nice to see that the problem has more than one way to be solved.
Also, I still don't understand the argument by Turaev, can you help me understand it? His proof looks so direct, it seems that there are a bit of work behind it
